# No basis change in a fusion ring allowed?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

Consider the Fibonacci category F: $A\bigotimes{A}=E\bigoplus{A}$.
A study by Study (SCNR :-) already 1890 listed all unital associative algebras (with rank<=4).
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Classification_of_low-dimensional_algebras). Now where is F? Not there in this form, because by a basis change it's isomorph to $A\bigotimes{A}=E$ (and that is listed). But the two are different fusion rings!

Thus: Are the "simple objects" of a fusion ring "marked" somehow and basis change is strictly forbidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's right, fusion rings have more data than just being a ring, they also have a preferred basis corresponding to the simple objects.  So two fusion rings can be isomorphic as rings but not as fusion rings.

Comment: There are lots of other rings out there, e.g. $H^*(G/P)$, that are pretty boring as rings but interesting as rings-with-bases.